# Excel Formula needs adjusting

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Please can someone help 'fine tune' this If formula that doesn't quite do what I need:

```
=IF(AV4=0,AP4,IF(OR(AV4>=70,AV4<=30),AP4-IF(AP4>16,4,IF(AP4<16,2,0)),AP4))
```

the changes I need are:

if the figure in AV is equal to or less than 30 it is deducting 4 (if AP is over 16)  or 2 (if AP is under 16) but it should be adding (not deducting) 4 or 2

Also if AP is = or < 16 up or down by 2 (at present it doesn't do anything if AP is  16

The full brief is as follows:

I have present handicaps in column AP - based on whether their present handicap is 16 and over or 16 and below - I need the following to happen based n results in column AU:

if a number in column AV is higher than 70 
 Present handicap over 16 (column AP) - decrease by 4
 Present handicap under 16 (column AP) - decrease by 2

if a number in column AV is less than 30 
 Present handicap over 16 (column AP)- increase by 4
 Present handicap under 16 (column AP) - increase by 2

If AP is = or < 16 up or down by 2 (if AV over 70 or less than 30)

If AV = 0 - it just copies the value of AP

All rows with a result between 31 an 69 between nothing happens and the handicap in column AP doesn't change

Comment: This can be greatly simplified with a `VLOOKUP` to a handicap table

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be giving intended results.  Check against your own data.

```
=IF(AV4>69,IF(AP4>16,AP4-4,AP4-2),IF(AV4<31,IF(AP4>16,AP4+4,AP4+2),AP4))
```